# Not setting integer in memory correctly

Tags: c, memory

**main.c**

```
List L;
Initialize(&L);
printf("%d\n", Size(&L));
```

**list.c**

```
void Initialize (List *L) {
    L = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (L == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to create memory for list. Exiting.");
        exit(1);
    }
    L->size = 0;
}

int Size (List *L) {
    return L->size;
}
```

What I want outputted would be a size of '0', however what I am getting is the max int sizeof '2673724'.  I am kind of confused at this point what is wrong with my code. Looking with gdb it looks like the Initialize() function is not actually modifying the List's size as it remains the same before and after entering the function.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `Initialize` function ignore the argument, allocate a buffer, write something to it, throw it away and cause memory leak.

Try this simple function using the same way as `Size`:

```
void Initialize (List *L) {
    L->size = 0;
}
```

Comment: That works. I have not worked in C for a little while and the last thing I did was working with linked lists instead of just lists so I am getting myself confused between the two. So I essentially did not need to allocate memory for this in order to make it work as it is in the stack instead of the heap?

Comment: You didn't have to allocate the memory in `Initialize` in this case because it was already allocated in the stack.

Comment: Okay thanks, I understand my silly mistake now. I was getting myself confused as I looked at my old code from implementing a **linked** list, instead of just a list.